# Flutter Xcode build failure after adding 1st-party dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

While building an app using Android Studio with the Flutter SDK I decided to get the shared_preferences plugin and play around with it. Soon after, I noticed that although the app was running fine on my Android device, it wouldn't build to run on Simulator. In an attempt to figure out a solution, I tried running it directly from Xcode but again, it's failing there too.

Following the errors, I opened the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m file where the editor is just saying "shared_preferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h file not found"

Running `flutter doctor` in the terminal doesn't give any useful info and running `pod install` doesn't help.

I've also tried adding FlutterFire plugins and they all produce the same result.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15409, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15168

Comment: Lol, I created thread #15168 

Comment: :D, I like cross-linking stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15099#issuecomment-372375566

> To apply the fix in [#15437](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/15437) to a Swift-based Flutter project created before the fix landed, add [these lines] to `ios/Podfile`.

Which I think means https://github.com/mravn-google/flutter/blob/e0c73220a6f69d341ce436244212277d83bc189b/packages/flutter_tools/templates/cocoapods/Podfile-swift#L70-L73

```
 # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7463
 target.headers_build_phase.files.each do |file|
   file.settings = { 'ATTRIBUTES' => ['Public'] }
 end
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it!

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem for many days in my Flutter app for iOS and have done almost everything explained here and in github.

My solution was (1) after "flutter upgrade" call "flutter run" (also you have to run simulator or attach device for a correct work of this command) and (2) after successful building of an app through the command line, mentioned above, close it and build in a regular way with Xcode via Product -> Build.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is android specific and not available in iOS. If you want to save something, I recommend you use [Method Channel(Platform Channel)](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) in [Flutter](http://flutter.io) to send it to the native layer and save it.

For iOS use [userDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) to save your data.

Additional info:

**How to save data using Shared Preference?**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.commit(); // Don't forget to commit when your changes are done.
```

To retrive data

```
// returns stored preference value
// If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

**How to save data using userDefaults?**

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave 
forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve saved data

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

**UPDATE :**

There is a flutter [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) which does this for us.

Add this to your **pubspec.yaml file**

```
dependencies:
shared_preferences: "^0.4.0"
```

And run in command line in your project root directory.

```
$ flutter packages get
```

Now in your Dart code you can use,

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Comment: Actually, the Flutter team created a plugin called "shared_preferences" specifically for this. My question is not actually about trying to save data. It's about adding plugins to a flutter project

Comment: Once you add your dependency go to root of your project folder and run "flutter packages get" in terminal, then try running your code again. Hopefully this should solve you issue.

Comment: Yes, what you're saying in your edit is exactly what I did from the start. It doesn't work and I'm apparently not the only one with this problem